# Unable to connect to Windows shared drive - I get repeatedly prompted for credentials

Tags: networking, mount, windows

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I have a Surface Pro running Windows 10.  I have a drive connected to my Windows machine with all my media on it and I want access it from the Ubuntu machine.

I shared the drive, giving full permissions and no password required.  When I mapped the drive from my OTHER windows machine, it prompted me for credentials and I put in my Windows credentials and boom, it worked!

I went to the the file explorer on my Ubuntu machine and put in smb://IPADDRESS and it prompted me for the credentials, and I put my Windows credentials in again, and boom, it works!  I can see the shared drive right there.

However when I click on the shared drive, it prompts me AGAIN for my credentials.  When I put in the exact same credentials, it simply repeats the window prompt.  If I put in gibberish for the credentials it tells me permission denied.

I'm at a loss at this point, if I put in my real credentials it just continually prompts me.  Not sure where to go at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT:  I was able to find a solution.  I was following this guide here: https://linhost.info/2012/05/mount-a-network-share-in-linux-ubuntu/

And it still wasn't working, but when I entered in the incorrect file path I noticed that gave me an Error rather than nothing (which was what was happening before).  It gave me an idea!  So I went back through windows and re-named my shared drive with no apostrophes and no white spaces, then I retried the guide above and it worked!  It appears the file path was not in a format Ubuntu liked so much, and now I have the drive in /mnt/share.  Thanks for the help and I thought I should provide my solution in case anyone was having the same problem.

Comment: when you type in the credentials, your are also prompted for password storing method. If you chose 'save forever' or alike, the credentials will be saved in the gnome keyring.  See `seahorse` app to review saved credentials.

Comment: Yes. When logging into smb://IPADDRESS I selected "Save Forever" and it worked.  Every time I go back it logs in me in automatically.  The credentials are correct in seahorse.

However they are not there for the actual drive I want to access.

Comment: not so clear to me

Comment: When this happens to me I'll use the dot slash style username ..
**.\myusername** It's shorthand to only use the windows local account.